# Merge array from two separated array

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 seperate arrays called `$all_requests_messages` and `$all_messages.`

These 2 array results  are taken from same table but on applying different queries .Now i need to merge 2 arrays and list the result based on the primary key of the table. Is it possible ?

```
$all_requests_messages = $this->users_model->getAllRequests_Messages($arr['user_id']);

$all_messages = $this->users_model->getTypeMessage($arr['user_id'],0);


$all_requests_messages = array_merge($all_messages,$all_requests_messages);
```

need to sort the $all_requests_messages based on primary key value of the table .

Comment: [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) or [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) come to mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Why not do your thing on query, subquery maybe.